# Bootstrap layout not splitting cards properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have a bootstrap container where I have card views inside the row tag. I want each row to have 3 cards equally distanced and in the center. To achieve this I have used `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">` But for some reason it places 1 card in each row instead of 3.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-haze-j9vvn?file=/src/App.tsx

Code:

```
<div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            {posts &&
              posts.map((test) => (
                <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
                  <div className="citizen-item" key={test.id}>
                    <div className="card">
                      <img
                        style={{
                          height: "100%",
                          width: "100%",
                          minHeight: "180px",
                          objectFit: "cover"
                        }}
                        src={test.backgroundImage}
                      />
                      <div>
                        {test.Title}
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        Access to 151
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <button className="findButton">FIND OUT MORE</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}

            {/* Find Out more Card */}
            <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>
              <div
                className="citizen-item"
                style={{ height: "100%", minHeight: "348.8px" }}
              >
                <div>
                  <div>
                    CARIBBEAN CITIZENSHIP
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <button className="findButton">APPLY NOW</button>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    COMPARE PROGRAMS
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: replace `<div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">`  with `<div className="col-6 col-md-4">`

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa tried it didnt work. You can test it out in the codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've restricted the container to be col-md-4, col-lg-4. This forces the cards to go onto the next line since the container is only 4 columns wide. The container should span to 12 columns for it to able to accommodate multiple cards in a row.

So I added below to your cards

- col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12
- display: inline-block

I added below code for your container to make it span to 12 columns

- col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12

Kindly refer the link below that's working fine after above changes

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-satoshi-46gt8?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: note that `col-md-4 col-lg-4` is redundant. it's exactly the same as just `col-md-4` by itself because smaller breakpoints cascade up. similarly, `col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12` is redundant and is exactly the same as `col-sm-12` alone.

Comment: I understand, I have updated the link to account for above :) I added all of those extra classes to be explicit about what I was thinking. I hope the above link helps you achieve your use case. Cheers!

Also note, even if it accounts for the same thing. Adding those additional classes makes your code more readable, but that's personal preference

Comment: @ChiragParyani Here actually my last card I wanted to be in line with the second row as the third card. But here it gets shifted to the next row

Comment: @JayModi You may check the link now, I have accounted for that last card as well. I had to add classes col-md-4 col-sm-12 and property display: inline-block for it to come on the second line

Comment: For some reason it is not aligned properly if you check it with inspect

Comment: @JayModi I just had a look at it - seems like the HTML structure for the last card is not consistent with other cards, this will require CSS work and that can be done quickly based on your usecase

For example, there's no .card class being used in the last card unlike other cards. So the layout is working just fine, the last cards needs some work